# What was used to bootstrap the C compiler

Tags: c

The C compiler was written in C, that much I know. What language/tools/instructions was/were used to create the initial functionality for the C compiler to become self-hosting?

UPDATE:

I know what bootstrapping a language is, and it is that research that prompted this question. I cannot find an answer to my question anywhere on SO.

Comment: No, *the* C compiler is written in C++.

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question is general and is answered by the bootstrapping technique. This one is about a specific compiler and the *language(s)* used to bootstrap it. Obviously this OP already knows about bootstrapping: he mentions it in his title.

Comment: @EJP, spot on. I definitely understand the concept of bootstrapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a multitude of C compilers in the world. Many of them were (and still are) written in C. However the first one was not - it was written in B.